# Bash script to complete 21 process by running 4 process parallel

Tags: bash

I am new to scripting. 
I have 21 directories to compress and copy to another location.
I want to run 4 process in parallel and if one process complete then start another one. like wise 21 directories should complete.

I got some idea from following post. 
[bash script to check running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903354/bash-script-to-check-running-process)

I need this to add, if number of running service < 4, then start another process.

Please help me regarding this matter.

My script is as follows. Here I used ping command to test process. If this is working I can arrange it to copy command.

job.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cat my.txt |while read line
do
 run_count=`ps eax | grep ping | grep -v grep | wc -l`
 if [ 4 -gt ${run_count} ]
 then
  /home/cms.sh $line &
 fi
done
```

cms.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$1
cmd=ping
host=yahoo.com

$cmd -c $1 $host >> log-$1.txt
```

my.txt

```
100
250
150
174
182
140
320
139
150
120
110 
99
156
180
230
132
123
119
156
149
162
```

If I run this, it is starting to run 4 process using first 4 lines in my.txt. After finish that initial 4 processes it will not continue remain values in my.txt.

Please let me know where I did mistake.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run bash commands in parallel, track results and count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384013/run-bash-commands-in-parallel-track-results-and-count)

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show us? How would you do this with one service?

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are new to scripting, take a look at `xargs -P`. It is a command worth becoming familiar with even if you are not running processes in parallel and it be somewhat more likely to be pre-installed on your system than `parallel` mentioned in the answer pointed to by Mat.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`pbzip2`: parallel bzip2 compression](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pbzip2) for this kind of purpose. Also, 7z has multi-threading options, but I haven't tried them

I use this kind of setup usually:

```
tar -cp somedir_tobackup/ | pbzip2 | mbuffer -m 180M | netcat <host> <port>
```

Obviously, you can use cpio instead, drop the mbuffer, save to a local archive file first, use rsync with it etc. but the idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel you can do:

```
cat my.txt | parallel /home/cms.sh
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). You command line with love you for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second loop just after your "do" that sleeps repeatedly for 1 second until there are not 4 processes running, and it then breaks out of the loop and starts a new process before reading  another line from your control file. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
   while :
   do
      run_count=`ps eax | grep  ping | grep -v grep | wc -l`
      [ 4 -gt ${run_count} ] && break;
      sleep 1
   done
   ./somejob $line &
done < my.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I reckon that you got quad cores thus 4 processes. Wrong solution.
Instead, count number of cores (this way it can be extended to dual cores, quad cores, 6 cores, etc, without manually changing process variable).
This example is the best I can in running bash parallel. It is made by dividing the task in how many cores you got, clone `script.cfg` in how many cores you got, runs them in background.
In this way, each core will compress only a part of those folders.

Create a folder let's say `bash`.
Inside, create other 2 folders (`backup` and `directory`).
Put those 21 folders inside `directory`.
Create 2 files (make `.sh` file executable).

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date '+%d_%B_%Y')
mkdir backup/$date
cores=$(ls  /proc/acpi/processor/ | wc -l)
cd directory
ls > ../list.result
cd ..
file_lines=$(cat list.result | wc -l)
let "split_lines=$file_lines/$cores"
let "split_lines=$split_lines+1"
split -d --lines=$split_lines list.result CPU
for script in `seq 1 $cores`
do
    let sufix=script-1
    cat script.cfg > "CPU0$sufix.script"
    chmod +x CPU0$sufix.script
    sed -i 's/filenumber/CPU0'$sufix'/g' CPU0$sufix.script
    ./CPU0$sufix.script &
done
exit
```

and script.cfg

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date '+%d_%B_%Y')
lenght=$(cat filenumber |wc -l)
counter=1
for x in `seq 1 $lenght`
do
    value="directory/"$(sed "${x}!d" filenumber)
    tar -zcvf $value.tar.gz $value
    mv directory/*.tar.gz backup/$date
done
rm *.script CPU* list.result
exit
```

All files in `directory` folder will be compressed using all cores in CPU and moved to backup folder.
This technique runs all cores at 100% so take care of CPU temperature.