# how to run simultaneous commands

Tags: multithreading, bash, parallel-processing

I have a bash script.

```
f1 () 
{ 
    for ((i=1; i<6; i++))
    do
        a=$(echo -e "\033[41m ")        
        echo -n " $a";
        echo -en "\033[0m";
        sleep 1;
        echo -en "\b";
        echo -n ' '
    done
}

f2 () 
{

    a=$(echo -e "\033[41m \033[0m") 
    echo -en "\033[5;50H$a"
    for ((i=1; i<6; i++))
    do
        echo -en "\b"
        echo -en ' '
        echo -en "\b\b"
        echo -n "$a"
        sleep 1
        echo -en "\033[0m"
    done
}

f1
f2
```

f1 shifts the object to the right;
f2 shifts another object to the left;

what can I do to execute both functions at the same time, so that I see both objects move at the same time?

```
#this wont work
f1 & 
f2 &
```

Comment: I installed parallel,though am getting error message after running the code in the answer.

Comment: the error message is :parallel: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.

Answer (score 1):

Run them in background with parallel:

```
  #export functions so parallel can see them
  export -f f1
  export -f f2
  #run both functions
  parallel f1 f2
```

Comment: also, `wait` is useful as well. Since it, well, waits for all subproceses to finish before continuing. To run something truly parallel, google `gnu parallel`

Comment: Oh, true, I didn't understand the last line, you need to use [parallel for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384013/run-bash-commands-in-parallel-track-results-and-count).

Comment: @computer10 this version does the job.

Comment: i need to install parallel for ubuntu 64 bit.can you give me immediate instructions. apt-get ... or link.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install parallel`

Comment: +1 for good/interesting answer, and tech support. Good luck to all.