# wget and bash error: bash: line 0: fg: no job control

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, xargs

I am trying to run a series of commands in parallel through `xargs`. I created a null-separated list of commands in a file `cmd_list.txt` and then attempted to run them in parallel with 6 threads as follows:

```
cat cmd_list.txt | xargs -0 -P 6 -I % bash -c %
```

However, I get the following error:

```
bash: line 0: fg: no job control
```

I've narrowed down the problem to be related to the length of the individual commands in the command list. Here's an example artificially-long command to download an image:

```
mkdir a-very-long-folder-de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8
wget --no-check-certificate --no-verbose -O a-very-long-folder-de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8/blah.jpg http://d4u3lqifjlxra.cloudfront.net/uploads/example/file/48/accordion.jpg
```

Just running the `wget` command on its own, without the file list and without `xargs`, works fine. However, running this command at the bash command prompt (again, without the file list) fails with the `no job control error`:

```
echo "wget --no-check-certificate --no-verbose -O a-very-long-folder-de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8/blah.jpg http://d4u3lqifjlxra.cloudfront.net/uploads/example/file/48/accordion.jpg" | xargs -I % bash -c %
```

If I leave out the long folder name and therefore shorten the command, it works fine:

```
echo "wget --no-check-certificate --no-verbose -O /tmp/blah.jpg http://d4u3lqifjlxra.cloudfront.net/uploads/example/file/48/accordion.jpg" | xargs -I % bash -c %
```

`xargs` has a `-s` (size) parameter that can change the max size of the command line length, but I tried increasing it to preposterous sizes (e.g., 16000) without any effect. I thought that the problem may have been related to the length of the string passed in to `bash -c`, but the following command also works without trouble:

```
bash -c "wget --no-check-certificate --no-verbose -O a-very-long-folder-de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8/blah.jpg http://d4u3lqifjlxra.cloudfront.net/uploads/example/file/48/accordion.jpg"
```

I understand that there are other options to run commands in parallel, such as the `parallel` command (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6497852/1410871), but I'm still very interested in fixing my setup or at least figuring out where it's going wrong.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite).

Comment: That exact pair of lines fails for you? It works here on CentOS. If that's the only pair of lines in the file does it still fail with xargs? Does it fail (when by itself) if you run `bash -c "$(< cmd_list.txt)"`?

Comment: @EtanReisner, although my goal is to use a file list, I have errors even before that step. This line fails: `echo "wget --no-check-certificate --no-verbose -O a-very-long-folder-de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8/blah.jpg http://d4u3lqifjlxra.cloudfront.net/uploads/example/file/48/accordion.jpg" | xargs -I % bash -c %`

Comment: @EtanReisner: Re: "That exact pair of lines fails for you? [...] If that's the only pair of lines in the file does it still fail with xargs?": I think you have that backward. The OP seems to be saying that it *only* fails when run via xargs.

Comment: There's no file yet at this point. I'm just running the above command at the bash prompt (after creating that long directory).

Comment: When I copied and pasted that from the comment it had weird characters in it? Are those in your original? What do you get if you echo that to `xxd`? Without the odd characters it works here.

Comment: Nothing given in this question is running `fg` at all -- so presumably there's something else in your environment that's doing so. I'd suggest using `bash -x -c '...'` with a PS4 that shows where code being run comes from (such as `PS4='+($?) $BASH_SOURCE:$FUNCNAME:$LINENO:'`) to debug the origin of that `fg` command.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I do not think that there are any non-ascii characters in any of my commands

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I tried your suggestion but I don't think it yielded much useful information. See https://gist.github.com/drdan14/2d6d32aa11d058e3e443.

Comment: @DanielGolden, it tells us the literal `%` is being given to the shell rather than substituted by xargs. That's useful information indeed.

Comment: As an aside, by the way -- `foo <in.txt` is considerably more efficient than `cat in.txt | foo` (try benchmarking it with `pv`!), and provides a real (seekable) file descriptor rather than a pipeline, allowing programs that can perform more efficiently when able to use the `seek()` call to do so.

Comment: ...indeed, `bash -c '%'` exits with `bash: line 0: fg: no job control`, again confirming that `xargs` isn't properly performing substitution.

Comment: I may have found a partial answer; in the [OS X xargs man page](http://bit.ly/14jgnhb), the help for the `-I` command reads, "The resulting arguments, after replacement is done, will not be allowed to grow beyond 255 bytes." The command as I've written it (everything in the quotes following `echo`) is 266 characters, which, I suppose, is 267 bytes including the null terminator. I don't see an obvious way to get around the 255-byte limit in the `xargs` documentation; maybe this is a hard limit and commands of a greater length can never work.

Comment: @DanielGolden, if GNU tools are available on your system, have you looked at `xargs -J` as opposed to `xargs -I`? `-I` is the POSIX form, which requires the 255-byte limit; `-J`, being an extension, is forced into no such limitation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68300/discussion-between-daniel-golden-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the solution is to avoid the `-I` parameter for `xargs` which, per the [OS X xargs man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html), has a 255-byte limit on the replacement string. Instead, the `-J` parameter is available, which does not have a 255-byte limit.

So my command would look like:

```
echo "wget --no-check-certificate --no-verbose -O a-very-long-folder-de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8/blah.jpg http://d4u3lqifjlxra.cloudfront.net/uploads/example/file/48/accordion.jpg" | xargs -J % bash -c %
```

However, in the above command, only the portion of the replacement string before the first whitespace is passed to bash, so bash tries to execute:

```
wget
```

which obviously results in an error. My solution is to ensure that `xargs` interprets the commands as null-delimited instead of whitespace-delimited using the `-0` parameter, like so:

```
echo "wget --no-check-certificate --no-verbose -O a-very-long-folder-de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8de090952623b4865c2c34bd6330f8a423ed05ed8/blah.jpg http://d4u3lqifjlxra.cloudfront.net/uploads/example/file/48/accordion.jpg" | xargs -0 -J % bash -c %
```

and finally, this works!

Thank you to @CharlesDuffy who provided most of this insight. And no thank you to my OS X version of `xargs` for its poor handling of replacement strings that exceed the 255-byte limit.

Comment: The only part of this answer I'm not sure of -- with respect to correctness -- is the claim that bash was only executing `wget`; from the `set -x` log you posted in comments, it looks like bash was executing `%` (which also explains the error message you got as a result, as `bash -c '%'` generates the reported error, whereas `bash -c 'wget'` does not).

Comment: Sorry, I put the more recent command higher in https://gist.github.com/drdan14/2d6d32aa11d058e3e443. The result was `+(0) ::0:wget`. So I don't think there was a problem related to `%`.

Comment: Actually -- that looks like a problem from lack of the `-0` argument to `xargs` (and `echo` rather than `printf '%s\0'`).

Comment: ...as `echo "hello" | xargs -0` doesn't actually have a NUL character anywhere (even on the end of the input stream), meaning you're depending on undefined behavior for it to do anything at all. `printf '%s\0' "echo 'hello world'" "echo 'goodbye world'"`, on the other hand, unambiguously delineates each command, leaving less room for variance based on `xargs` implementation decisions.

Comment: In the case where you get `+(0) ::0:wget`, by the way, do you also get the `no job control` error given in this post's title?

Comment: No, in that case, the only error is the `wget` not enough arguments error.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's the percent symbol, and your top shell complaining.

> cat cmd_list.txt | xargs -0 -P 6 -I % bash -c %

Percent is a metacharacter for job control. "fg %2", e.g.  "kill %4".

Try escaping the percents with a backslash to signal to the top shell that it should not try to interpret the percent, and xargs should be handed a literal percent character.

> cat cmd_list.txt | xargs -0 -P 6 -I \% bash -c \%

Comment: I suspect that this _is_ related to why the specific error at hand (referencing job control) is being given, but also that the proposed fix isn't going to work: The logs given from a `bash -x` invocation (linked in the comments) show that it's the shell started by xargs giving the error, not the outer shell responsible for invoking xargs -- and (a) the escaping being done here doesn't carry through to the inner shell, and (b) xargs is supposed to replace the `%` with the literal command text anyhow.

Comment: @ChadMiller, Your theory makes sense, but escaping the `%` has no effect; results are the same as with the unescaped `%`.